# How can I get error logs when executing the S3 client in a lambda context?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-js-v3

The lambda function handler below does not log anything after the line `console.log('Getting already imported files list...');`. The function just times out (30s for example).

The bucket 'testbucket' is not available (intentionally). Though, I am not getting any error messages or other log messages.
How can I enable them?

```js
import { ListObjectsV2Command, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

export const handler = async (): Promise<unknown> => {
  try {
    const s3Client = new S3Client({
      region: 'eu-west-3',
      logger: {
        error: (...messages: string[]): void => console.log(...messages),
        warn: (...messages: string[]): void => console.log(...messages),
        info: (...messages: string[]): void => console.log(...messages),
        debug: (...messages: string[]): void => console.log(...messages),
      },
      maxAttempts: 1,
    });

    console.log('Getting already imported files list...');

    const res = await s3Client.send(
      new ListObjectsV2Command({
        Bucket: 'testbucket',
      }),
    );

    console.log({ res });

    console.log('Ended :)');

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      message: 'ok?',
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error caught...');

    console.log(error);

    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      message: 'Internal server error.',
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: Is this Lambda function running in a VPC?

Comment: Try increasing your Lambda timeout to 300 seconds and you should see an error.

Comment: To explain what MarkB said: if you're running in a VPC, the only way for the Lambda to access anything outside the VPC is for (1) it to have a VPC endpoint, or (2) it's running in a subnet that routes external traffic through a NAT.

Comment: I guess that the VPC was the issue. However, the problem still was that I did not get any error logs at all. If something is inaccessible, I expect to have some error message that it is not accessible.